# Return field from first and last document in Elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a sorted elasticsearch histogram aggregation that works fine as is.

I need to return a field from the first and last document of each aggregation bucket.

Current query (ruby-style syntax):

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {
      filter: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            { term: { some_id: 'something' } },
            { range: {
                completed_at: {
                  gte: start,
                  lte: end
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      _cache: true,
      _cache_key: "special-query"
    }
  },
  aggs: {
    intervals: {
      histogram: {
        field: 'completed_at',
        interval: 24.hours.to_i,
        min_doc_count: 0,
        order: { _key: 'asc' }
      },
      aggs: {
        start_at: { min: { field: 'completed_at' } },
        end_at: { max: { field: 'completed_at' } },
        price_stats: { extended_stats: { field: 'rate' } },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have searched through the documentation and googled extensively but can't find any solutions. Currently I have to send a second query to the database to explicitly fetch all the values for this field but I would like to roll that functionality in to my elasticsearch query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to return a result per aggregation right?

That's called Field Collapsing and unfortunately isn't yet available in Elasticsearch, see: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256

**Update sept 2014**

As per @bpierce in comments below: Now that [Elasticsearch 1.3.x](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-3-0-released/) is out, field collapsing is available via the top_hits aggregation. I'm currently using it in a query similar to this one.

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for. Pity it's not implemented, I'll have to just keep working around it with a query to the DB. Thanks.

Comment: If you're not 100% bound to Elastichsearch, Solr DOES provide this functionality. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

Comment: Now that [Elasticsearch 1.3.x is out](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-3-0-released/), field collapsing is available via the `top_hits` aggregation.  I'm currently using it in a query similar to this one.